# PowerShell: Is there an automatic variable for the last execution result?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a feature comparable to Python interactive shell's "_" variable. In PowerShell I want something like this:

```
> Get-Something # this returns an object and display it to the output.
# Now I want to assign that object to some variable
> $anObj = ???
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No there is not automatic variable like that.

You have to do:

```
$output = Get-Something
$output
$anObj = $output
```

to get the behaviour

Comment: This is the first time I've been disappointed by PowerShell. Usually, it there's always a way to do anything that I can dream of.

Comment: really feels like an oversight. Why do we get `$$` and `$^` (whose usecase eludes me) but nothing like `%` or `ANS` or `_` in many other shells/repls?

Comment: @masterxilo Because it's a very large amount of memory overhead to always preserve the last set of objects in memory.  What if the last command output 6,000,000 objects?  Remember that PowerShell can stream objects through the pipeline, so it doesn't necessarily need to ever have the entire collection in memory at once to just display them.  It's better to assume that if the user actually wants to retain the output of a command that they'll take a minimal amount of effort and assign it to a variable.

Comment: @BaconBits "minimal amount of effort" != foresight. :-) I presently have 6 hung WPF windows open right now because I'm testing a XAML previewer app and neglected to either save off the `$window` or call `$window.Close()` where I had a reference... I'll fix it before I run out of memory, surely!

Comment: I'm constantly regretting it when I run a command that takes minutes to finish and didn't think to capture it in a variable. At this point I've gotten used to just always doing something like `$test = Get-Whatever; $test` instead of running the bare cmdlet. However this kind of corrupts my history, because then I can't just start typing `Get-Whatev` and see the last similar commandline I ran without remembering what the variable name I used was. I may need to start remembering to use `Tee-Object` or `-Out-Variable` instead, so that "corruption" doesn't happen.

Answer (score 27):

**tl;dr**

- **Such an *automatic* variable does *not* exist** as of PowerShell 7.3.3, and there  may never be one.

  - You can **create your own**, with limitations, as detailed in the **next section**.
- **Ad hoc**, **for a given command** you can use **[`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object)** `-Variable` or, more simply - for *cmdlets* and *advanced* scripts / functions only - the [common **`-OutVariable`** parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonParameters#-outvariable) to ***both* print results *to the display* and *also capture them* in a variable**; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Tee-Object cmdlet: Works with any command.
  # Captured result will be available in self-chosen variable $r
  # Note: Do NOT use "$" in the -OutVariable argument.
  $PSVersionTable | Tee-Object -Variable r

  # -OutVariable common parameter: Works with cmdlets, advanced scripts / funcs.
  # Captured result will be available in self-chosen variable $r
  # Note: Do NOT use "$" in the -OutVariable argument.
  Get-ChildItem *.txt -OutVariable r
  ```

---

##### Simple, but limited PSv3+ solution to create a quasi-automatic variable containing the most recent execution results:

Note:

- For a proper, but nontrivial solution, see [BartekB's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354043/45375).
- [GitHub feature request #7853](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7853) asks for building this functionality into a future PowerShell (Core) version (the current version as of this writing is PowerShell (Core) 7.3.3).

---

Add the following to your `$PROFILE` file:

```bash
# Store previous command's output in $__
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-Default:OutVariable'] = '__'
```

<sup>What to name the variable - such as `$__` (2 underscores) in this example - is up to you, but **beware of name collisions, notably with `$_`**, the *automatic* variable that represents the input object at hand in a number of contexts.</sup>

**This will capture the *terminal-bound* output of the most recently executed *PowerShell* command [that produced terminal output] in variable `$__` in your interactive sessions**,
by way of PowerShell's ability to globally preset parameter defaults - see [`Get-Help about_Parameters_Default_Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values).

`-OutVariable` is a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) designed to collect a cmdlet's / advanced function's output objects in a variable, and the above definition applies this parameter *implicitly* to all `Out-Default` calls, which in turn is called behind the scenes whenever PowerShell outputs something to the terminal - however, note the exceptions mentioned below.

**Caveats**:

- **If needed, use `$saved = $__.Clone()` to save the captured output for later use**, given that `$__` is reassigned to on every command (of course, if you know ahead of time that you want to keep a command's output, use an assignment to begin with: `$saved = <command>`).

  - Note that just `$saved = $__` does *not* work, because that makes `$saved` point to the same `[ArrayList]` instance as `$__`, which gets repopulated on the next command.
- **Output is *not* captured** in the following cases:

  - **Output from *external programs***, such as `git`, because by design PowerShell passes the output streams from external programs directly to the terminal (unless they're redirected or captured), and therefore doesn't call `Out-Default`. The simplest workaround is to pipe to `Write-Output` (something like `*>&1` to explicitly route through PowerShell streams doesn't work); e.g.:

    - `whoami.exe | Write-Output   # $__ is now populated`
  - **Output from commands that *explicitly call a formatting cmdlet*** - `Format-Custom`, `Format-Hex`, `Format-List`, `Format-Table`, or `Format-Wide`.

    - It's tempting to attempt to fix that with `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Format-*:OutVariable'] = '__'`, but, unfortunately, this would collect *formatting objects* (instructions) rather than the *original data* in `$__`, which is undesired.
      An unsatisfying workaround is to capture `Format-*` output in a *different* variable, which not only requires you to think about which variable you need to target, but you'll still only see formatting objects rather than data, and, since `Format-*` cmdlets are involved behind the scenes even if you don't use them explicitly, the output of commands *without* `Format-*` calls is then captured *twice* - once as data, in `$__`, and again as formatting objects, in the other variable.
- Due to a [design quirk](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154), **`$__`  *always* contains an *array list*** (of type `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`), even if the previous command output only a *single* object. When in doubt, use `$($__)` (or `$__[0]`) to get a single output object as such.
- Beware of commands producing very large output sets, because `$__` will collect them *in memory*.
- `$__` will only capture objects output to the *terminal* - just like `_` does in Python; a command that produces no output or `$null` / an array of `$null`s leaves any previous `$__` value intact.

Answer (score 8):

You can also print the result of the command and capture the output object(s) using the  OutVariable parameter, later on then use $anObj to display the variable content.

```
Get-Something -OutVariable anObj
```

Comment: This is great to know. Usually I just want to up arrow and correct my previous command entry. Tacking -OutVariable r at the end is easier than moving cursor to beginning of line and adding $r =

Answer (score 7):

Last option that requires most work but IMO gives you what you ask for: create proxy that will overwrite Out-Default (that is always called implicitly at the end of pipeline, if you don't out-* to something else).

Jeffrey Snover gave presentation on it during one of PowerShell Deep Dives (I reckon it was the first one) - you can find scripts he used (including above mentioned out-default) on [Dmitry Sotnikov blog](http://dmitrysotnikov.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/scripts-tec-2011-jeffrey-snover-proxy-functions.pdf). You can also watch [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWgPYWf1ZaA) from it to understand whole concept.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. There's the $_ automatic value which contains the current object **in the pipe-line**.

The pipeline is the usual way to pass a result from one cmdlet to the next, and cmdlets are set to accept parameters from the pipeline or from the properties of objects in the pipeline making the use of a "last result" variable irrelevant.

Still some situations do require a specific reference to the "piped" object and for those there's the $_ automatic value.

Here's an example of its usage: [Using the Where-Object Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) and here's a list of powershell's automatic variables: [Chapter 4. PowerShell Automatic Variables](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/microsoft-windows-powershell/9780596521783/powershell-automatic-variables/powershell_automatic_variables)

Scripting in powershell requires a different style than programming in Python (same as Python requires a different style than C++.)

Powershell is built so pipes are used extensively, if you want to break up a pipeline into a more procedural step by step structure you'll need to save your results in named variables not automatic ones.

Comment: I don't see why the Repl UI cannot do this for you. Notebook style interfaces (think mathematica & jupyter) even save every displayed output in a variable. Especially if the command is (unexpectedly) long running, you will be thankful for a variable.

Answer (score 3):

How about invoking the last command with "r" (alias for Invoke-History) and wrapping it in parentheses() to execute it first?

Yes this reruns the last command, but in my use cases this is by far the most streamlined solution especially for times when I don't realize that I'll need the last commands output at first.

It also keeps the object structure intact.

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 3 | Where {$_.State -match "2"}

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM          3 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX       100 Mbps

PS C:\Users\user> (r) |where {$_.LinkSpeed -eq "100 Mbps"}
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 3 | Where {$_.State -match "2"}

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM          3 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX       100 Mbps

PS C:\Users\user> (r).MacAddress
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 3 | Where {$_.State -match "2"}
XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
```

Comment: This only works for "idempotent" commands. It is, at best, useless for commands that change state. (And potentially produce dangerous/unexpected consequences)

Answer (score 2):

For my specific use case, I was running a batch file from PowerShell, and I wanted to print the output of that batch file in  real-time AND save the output into a variable.  I was able to accomplish this by piping the output of my call operator to `Tee-Object`:

```
$args = @('-r', '-a');
& "C:\myFile.bat" $args | Tee-Object -Variable output;
$output | Set-Clipboard;
```

The first command sets up my arguments for the batch file.  The second command runs the batch file using the call operator with my arguments, and it pipes the output to the `Tee-Object` command, which prints the output in real-time from the call operator, but also saves all the information into a new variable called *output*.  The last command simply copies the contents of `$output` to the clipboard.

`Tee-Object` also allows saving output to a file (Unicode encoding), and if I need to save to a file *and* a variable (in addition to printing to the console), I can chain multiple calls to `Tee-Object` together in one pipeline.  See this link for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object

Comment: Thanks! None of the other upvoted answers worked for me, they either threw an error or the output variable was blank - this worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This is from Windows Powershell in Action.  Source this in your $profile, and it makes $last contain the output of the last command.  It also will change directories by typing the name of the directory a la zsh, or go to a website in a browser by typing the url of the website.  It makes an Out-Default function that overrides the Out-Default cmdlet and calls it.  I added the "start-process $__command" line so going to a website would work in osx.

This is fairly invasive.  I later disabled it in my $profile for some reason.

```
#
# Wrapping an exiting command with a function that uses
# steppable pipelines to "remote-control" the wrapped command.
    
function Out-Default
{
  [CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact="Medium")]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] $InputObject
  )
    
  begin {
    $wrappedCmdlet = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCmdlet(
      "Out-Default")
    $sb = { & $wrappedCmdlet @PSBoundParameters }
    $__sp = $sb.GetSteppablePipeline()
    $__sp.Begin($pscmdlet)
  }

  process {
    $do_process = $true
    if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
      if ($_.Exception -is 
      [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]) {
        $__command = $_.Exception.CommandName
        if (test-path -path $__command -pathtype container) {
          set-location $__command
          $do_process = $false
        }
        elseif ($__command -match '^http://|\.(com|org|net|edu)$') {
          if ($matches[0] -ne "http://") {$__command = "HTTP://" + 
            $__command }
          # [diagnostics.process]::Start($__command)
          start-process $__command
          $do_process = $false
        } 
      } 
    }
    if ($do_process) {
      $global:LAST = $_;
      $__sp.Process($_)
    }  
  }

  end {
    $__sp.End()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that has worked for me is to process the command's output with `Select-Object` as a pass-through. For instance, I had a console EXE that output verbose output to `stderr` and meaningful output to `stdout`, of which I wanted to capture only the last line.

```
$UtilityPath = ""

(UpdateUtility.exe $ArgList 2>&1) | % {
    If ($_ -Is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
    Else {
        $_
        $UtilityPath = $_
    }
}
```

The way this script was being invoked, having output on PowerShell's `Error` output stream was considered a hard error, which didn't mesh nicely with the way PowerShell takes external apps' `stderr` output and turns it into `Error` output. This approach of wrapping the output allowed me to control how it passed through, as well as capture the `stdout` line I wanted. It seems to me that this would be a fairly flexible approach that would allow you to intercept output and do anything you want with it as it passes through. For instance:

```
$CommandOutput = ""

SomeOtherCommand | % {
    $CommandOutput += "$_`r`n"
    $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try putting you initial command in "( )", i.e:

> **($anObj = Get-Something)** # this returns an object and display it to the output AND creates a variable called $anObj, containing that "display" output.

Answer (score -1):

Use the module PowerShellCookbook and add a call to Add-ObjectCollector to your startup script

Comment: This is a small fragment of what's considered a good SO answer: a good answer would link to the module and, as a minimum, call out the lines that implement the answer so that someone can see how to do it from scratch.