# how to programmatically access buffer in dos command window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I used the word "programmatically" but I'm not sure it's the right one... 
I'll try to explain the question with an example

if I do:

```
dir /S/B | find "something"
```

and I receive 10 different file than I would like,  instead of copy and paste, just to type

```
del @1
```

where 1 is the first line produced by last command and @ is a magic symbol to access the buffer.

Of course I would like to have this feature whatever is the command (not only for dir).

Comment: Any thought of maybe learning PowerShell, and not "DOS" (which is not DOS, I hope you know).

Comment: See [Scripting with Windows Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, PowerShell looks powerful but it doesn't seems to support this feature natively  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351018/powershell-is-there-an-automatic-variable-for-the-last-execution-result)

Comment: Sure does. The output of a `dir` command is an array of `FileInfo`. Store it in a variable and you can process the files later. You won't even need the `dir`. `$a =dir`, `$a`.